# display inline-block not working with margin

Tags: css

Why are these two elements not inlined?

I would expect the two elements to be vertical aligned

http://jsfiddle.net/3tcsn8z6/

```
<div class="label">Input label</div>
<div class="input">
    <div></div>
</div>

.label,
.input {
    display:inline-block;
}

.label {
    margin:2px 8px;
    font-size:11px;
}

.input {
    margin:10px 2px;
}

.input > div {
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `vertical-align: middle`. The default value is `baseline`. The margin is somewhat irrelevant.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/jw8xx302/)

```
.label,
.input {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```